# Implementing custom algorithm in H2O

Tags: h2o

I am looking to implement a constrained conditional model in H2O. Are there any resources that can help me get started on implementing a new framework in H2O ?

I have been looking at the github repo. Would I start by looking at implementations of hex.Model as a starting point to understand how to implement?

If there are any samples, etc., would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you taken a look at https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md? you can also post to gitter https://gitter.im/h2oai/h2o-3.

Comment: I think Lauren's comment might qualify as an answer.